# Nest Device Access - device-id not unique

Tags: nest-device-access

I'm currently developing an integration with [Nest Device Access](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access) and I've seen that the same device shared between different nest accounts don't have a matching device-id.

When requesting the [devices list](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/use-the-api#list_structures_and_devices),of two different users, the device-id reference of the same phisical nest doesn't correspond.

I guess that the device-id is set per user. My problem is that I need to identify a physical nest between accounts, and for that I need a unique device-id to identify it, which I'm unable to find. Is there a way to find this unique Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to uniquely identify a device across multiple users. As you indicate, it is both per-device and per-user.